# How to play RTMP stream in android app using media3?

Tags: android, exoplayer, rtmp, live-streaming, android-media3

I have used libvlc (VLC library) to play the stream but the stream has delay of 6 sec.
Does anyone know how to play rtmp stream using Exoplayer?

I tried using exoplayer (media3) but it's not working.
I am using kotlin and jetpack compose to develop app.

Comment: Please share the code that you have used using media3.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.